# Read Logs Based on Current Time Stamp

Tags: shell, unix, logging

I have a log file like this:(example.log)

```
2016-06-13 04:50:10.327 39571893 [Thread-39-a-b-c-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.i.i.b.abcBolt - Setting other variation theme
2016-06-13 04:50:10.327 39571893 [Thread-39-a-b-c-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.i.i.b.abcBolt - Stripping abc hierarchy
2016-06-13 04:50:10.328 39571894 [Thread-39-a-b-c-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.i.i.b.abcBolt - Transforming date attributes
2016-06-13 04:50:10.328 39571894 [Thread-39-a-b-c-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.i.i.b.abcBolt - Creating API object for incoming data
```

Now I only want to read logs of last 4 hour(not last 4 hours from the last log but last 4 hrs from the current system time; there may be 0 logs but then empty file must be created) and store the logs(exactly unchanged) in a separate file. Can I just compare the timestamp or I have to extract hour, minute and second and apply logic?

My attempt:

```
x=$((4*3600))
current = date
awk -F 'JobLoader' -v current=$current -v x=$x '{ ______ | getline d; if (current-d<=x)print $0 }' example.log > output.txt
```

I am having trouble on how to grep the current time of the current log and whether I can compare like I did?

Actually I have a continuous operation with the logs to do i.e. extract the 16th and 20th field into a separate file. I am doing this based on suggestions:

```
awk ' {
    cutoff=$(date -d "now -4 hours" +%s)
    date=$(cut -c1-19 <<<"$line")
    ts=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
    if [ $cutoff -le $ts ]; then
        print $3
    fi    
} ' /home/example.log >> output.txt
```

But I am getting error as:

```
awk: cmd. line:2:     cutoff=$(date -d "now -4 hours" +%s)
awk: cmd. line:2:                                      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:     date=$(cut -c1-19 <<<"$line")
awk: cmd. line:3:                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:4:     ts=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
awk: cmd. line:4:                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:5:     if [ $cutoff -le $ts ]; then
awk: cmd. line:5:                          ^ syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest solution based on awk only. I can't use sed etc.

Comment: Have you some attempts at a solution? That will help frame the need in context and suggest what tools you want to use (`awk`, `grep`, etc.).

Comment: @bishop :  I have tried the above. But as said, not getting what to fill in there?

Comment: Will every line start with a date, or can you have stacktraces or other multi-line output ?

Comment: as you have used the `unix` tag, you'll need to be explicit about what version of `awk` you have available. Indicate what OS you are running on. If `awk --version` returns information, then add that to your Q. If you have recent version of `gawk` available, then that is better. Else, maybe your system has `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, which would be better than `nawk` or `oawk` (oldawk`), etc. Good luck.

Comment: @WalterA: Every line starts with a date.

Comment: @shellter: I have GNU Awk 4.0.1;

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this: `awk` and `perl` spring to mind. Personally, I like just a pure bash solution:

```
cutoff=$(date -d "now -4 hours" +%s)
while read line; do
    date=$(cut -c1-19 <<<"$line")
    ts=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
    if [ $cutoff -le $ts ]; then
        echo "$line"
    else
        break
    fi
done < <(tac $1)
```

Here's what's happening:

- First line, we establish the cutoff time as a UNIX timestamp (`%s`), which is four hours in the past from the current clock (`now -4 hours`)
- Then for every line in the given file, *reading from the last line to the first* (`tac $1`)
- We cut out the date part, which is the first 20 characters (`-c1-19`), then convert that to a UNIX timestamp (`-d "$date"`)
- Then we compare the log line timestamp with the cutoff: if the log line date is larger than the cutoff, we print the line. If not, we end the loop.

Of course this assumes your log files are monotonically increasing and that each line begins with a date. Also that you have access to GNU date and tac. If you want lots of portability, awk is the way to go. If you want a knock off script, well, I'd use bash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But just want to know, how can we do it if we want to do it using awk, like what i tried.